# How to create a pandas dataframe from a nested json file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I have a json file which looks like this:**

```
{
    "data": {
        "success": true,
        "timeseries": true,
        "start_date": "2022-10-01",
        "end_date": "2022-10-04",
        "base": "EUR",
        "rates": {
            "2022-10-01": {
                "NG": 0.1448939471560284
            },
            "2022-10-02": {
                "NG": 0.14487923291390148
            },
            "2022-10-03": {
                "NG": 0.1454857922753868
            },
            "2022-10-04": {
                "NG": 0.1507352356663182
            }
        },
        "unit": "per MMBtu"
    }
}
```

**I want to create a dataframe which looks like this:**

```
Date        NG        base 
2022-10-01  0.144894  EUR
2022-10-02  0.144879  EUR
2022-10-03  0.145486  EUR
2022-10-04  0.150735  EUR
```

**This is what I tried:**

```
with open(r'C:\Users\EH\Desktop\tools\json_files\blue_file.json','r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data['data']['rates'])
df1 = df1.T
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data['data'])
df2 = df2.base

merge = [df1, df2]
df3 = pd.concat(merge)

print(df3)
```

**My current output:**

```
                  NG    0
2022-10-01  0.144894  NaN
2022-10-02  0.144879  NaN
2022-10-03  0.145486  NaN
2022-10-04  0.150735  NaN
2022-10-01       NaN  EUR
2022-10-02       NaN  EUR
2022-10-03       NaN  EUR
2022-10-04       NaN  EUR
```

As you can see something is not going okay, I dont understand where the NaNs come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the file is stored in a variable called data

```
data = { "data": { "success": True, "timeseries": True, "start_date": "2022-10-01", "end_date": "2022-10-04", "base": "EUR", "rates": { "2022-10-01": { "NG": 0.1448939471560284 }, "2022-10-02": { "NG": 0.14487923291390148 }, "2022-10-03": { "NG": 0.1454857922753868 }, "2022-10-04": { "NG": 0.1507352356663182 } }, "unit": "per MMBtu" } }
```

First, one will read the data to a dataframe with [`pandas.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['data']['rates'], orient='index')

[Out]:
                  NG
2022-10-01  0.144894
2022-10-02  0.144879
2022-10-03  0.145486
2022-10-04  0.150735
```

But, as one wants doesn't want the columns with date to be the index, and one wants that column to have the name `Date`, one will start by resetting the index using [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
df = df.reset_index()

[Out]:
        index        NG
0  2022-10-01  0.144894
1  2022-10-02  0.144879
2  2022-10-03  0.145486
3  2022-10-04  0.150735
```

And then one will be able to rename the columns to the desired output format [`pandas.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

```
df = df.rename(columns={'index':'Date'})

[Out]:

         Date        NG
0  2022-10-01  0.144894
1  2022-10-02  0.144879
2  2022-10-03  0.145486
3  2022-10-04  0.150735
```

As it is still missing the base column, one can pick it up from the `data` as follows

```
df['base'] = data['data']['base']

[Out]:

         Date        NG base
0  2022-10-01  0.144894  EUR
1  2022-10-02  0.144879  EUR
2  2022-10-03  0.145486  EUR
3  2022-10-04  0.150735  EUR
```

Even though one already has the desired output, one can wrap everything into a one-liner as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['data']['rates'], orient='index').reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Date'}).assign(base=data['data']['base'])

[Out]:
         Date        NG base
0  2022-10-01  0.144894  EUR
1  2022-10-02  0.144879  EUR
2  2022-10-03  0.145486  EUR
3  2022-10-04  0.150735  EUR
```

Comment: Plus one for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Using what you had done, you just needed to specify the axis on which you want to concatenate the 2 dataframes by default pandas concatenated one below the other.

```
pd.concat(merge, axis=1) # default 0
```

Comment: Plus one for answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a very flexible format and no function in pandas can parse all types of JSON. You need to preprocess the JSON before constructing the dataframe:

```py
with open("data.json") as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [(date, rate["NG"]) for date, rate in data["data"]["rates"].items()],
    columns=["Date", "NG"],
).assign(base=data["data"]["base"])
```

Comment: That is some very long code of line. How do you even come up with it? But it works!

Answer (score 0):

simply:

```
import json
with open(r'path.json','r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

df=pd.DataFrame(data['data']).reset_index()
df=df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('rates')))
print(df)

df=df[['index','NG','base']]
df=df.rename(columns={'index':'Date'})
'''
    index      success  timeseries  start_date  end_date    base    unit    NG
0   2022-10-01  true    true    2022-10-01  2022-10-04  EUR per MMBtu   0.1448939471560284
1   2022-10-02  true    true    2022-10-01  2022-10-04  EUR per MMBtu   0.14487923291390148
2   2022-10-03  true    true    2022-10-01  2022-10-04  EUR per MMBtu   0.1454857922753868
3   2022-10-04  true    true    2022-10-01  2022-10-04  EUR per MMBtu   0.1507352356663182

'''
```

Comment: Not going to downvote, but the output doesn't look quite the same as what the OP is asking.

Comment: I thought the person asking the question could filter the columns. But you're right, I'm updating.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. The reason you are getting `NaN`s is that you need to specify different axis when concatenating the dataframes: `pd.concat(merge, axis=1)`.

Here is my version:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

with open("blue_file.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data["data"]["rates"], orient="index")
df["base"] = data["data"]["base"]
df
```

Output:

```
                  NG base
2022-10-01  0.144894  EUR
2022-10-02  0.144879  EUR
2022-10-03  0.145486  EUR
2022-10-04  0.150735  EUR
```